# Best transition to fast forward video

Tags: premiere, transitions

I have about 17 minutes of footage which I would like to preserve "as is" as it has lots of authenticity to it.

The problem is that some scenes are just boring to watch, but I don't want to cut them. Ideally, I would like to fast forward them. But when I increase the  speed of the video, it just does not look very nice or natural. The video is from my motorbike, so some passages are interesting and some are not. But I would like to have whole route on the resulting video.

My question is, do you know of any transition which I can apply for such a situation?

I'm using Adobe Premiere and the footage is in Full HD 60fps. I can reduce the frame rate or resolution, if transition effect requires.

Thank you

Comment: There is no magic transition that will help you. Simple cuts usually work best. A fade through black may help convey a sense of time passing. The most important thing is to think about the story you want to tell. Select the material that is important to telling that story, edit it together with cuts, and then add complex transitions only if you need to work around something awkward like a jump cut. People won't want to watch the uninteresting parts if you keep everything.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I also felt it that way, just I'm newbie in video production so I rather ask. Will cut it and use black screen for transitions

Comment: @MichaelLiebman, why not put that in an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @RyanWeaver, I thought it was kind of a non-answer, but since you and the OP disagree with that, I'm happy to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic transition that will help you. Simple cuts usually work best. A fade through black may help convey a sense of time passing. The most important thing is to think about the story you want to tell. Select the material that is important to telling that story, edit it together with cuts, and then add complex transitions only if you need to work around something awkward like a jump cut. People won't want to watch the uninteresting parts if you keep everything.